# Does STL library differ on different platforms?

Tags: c++, stl

Is C++ Standard Template Library (STL) on Windows different than the one on Linux OR any other Platform? Are the headers of STL differ with platform as well OR is STL just a header library and its implementation in CRT?

We know that compiler differ with platform and also the C Runtime Library differ with Platform. Going by this is it true that even Standard Template Library (STL) differ with platform?

Please clarify this doubt.

Also, what is the name of the C++ STL on windows and whats on Linux?

I have been trying to understand this by going various articles online and trying to frame a single workflow in my mind to understand the terms better.

Comment: What do you mean by "the name of the C++ STL"?

Comment: @gast128 - Did you mean that MAP and Vector on windows is same as MAP and Vector on linux?

Comment: The STL was a library put out by HP and later SGI back in the 90's. It probably had conditional blocks for different compilers and OSes in its source. The specifications of large chunks of it were adopted into the first C++ standard, and different compiler vendors have their own implementations of the standard library...

Comment: Is a wooden spoon the same as a silver spoon?

Comment: @IgorG I was the Golden Spoon mathematician in my final year at Cambridge (lowest 1st class degree). The wooden spoon was given to the person with the lowest 3rd class degree.

Comment: @Testuser. you need to specify which vendor's implementation you use. The STL only describes the expected behavior of std::map, e.g. O(log(n)) performance in lookup. In practice most use a red - black tree in the implementation but anything adhering to the specification is STL compliant.

Comment: @gast128 - so will it be right to say that vector and map adhere to Same specifications but underlying implementation might differ?

Comment: @TestUser: Boom! Exactly that.

Answer (score 8):

The *specification* of the C++ Standard Library is not contingent on any particular platform or compiler, although it does depend on the target C++ *standard*, and its behaviour is dependent function on various properties of a platform.

But the *implementation* of the C++ Standard Library is extremely dependent on the compiler and operating system. Some of the C++ Standard Library can even hardcoded into compilers.

But you use it in the same way. E.g. for `std::cout` and `std::cin` you should *always* write `#include <iostream>` as that's what the documentation says you're supposed to do. The names of header files can vary between implementations, but the ones you are supposed to use directly never differ.

This is why it's a good idea not to rely on `#include`s being available implicitly via other headers, or by using fancy non-standard `#include`s like `<bits/...>`. If you do so then you are not writing portable C++.

Comment: Actually, you don't "always need to include" the same headers to use various things. Some implementations might have other header interdependencies in which case your code works fine with one standard library implementation but not another. Of course, it's always programmer error for not including what you use, but

Comment: @rubenvb: Don't I make that clear in my final paragraph? (Although I have made an edit following your comment.)

Comment: Now it's better yes. The wording was a bit strong in the first version :).

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes I'm rather dogmatic for a cat.

Comment: Actually the specification has platform specific elements in it, as: time functions returning 0 if the platform doesn't have a clock. Although the c++ interface would be the same, the behavior can be different

Answer (score 5):

C++ was designed for abstract hardware but Standard C++ Library **implementations** differ, yes. Library vendors are required to follow the C++ Standard rules but are free to provide their implementation where allowed (the *implementation defined* wording in the standard). Headers also differ.

Comment: Thanks for removing that final paragraph. Downvote converted to upvote.